# Hatte „bleiben“ je eine Funktion als Hilfsverb?

Tags: grammar, verb

Die Kopulae „werden“ und „sein“ haben fungieren als Hilfsverb diverser grammatikalisierter Formen:

**Werden**

- Inchoativ (†): „Ich werde *gehend*.“
- Vorgangspassiv: „Die Haare werden *gekämmt*.“
- Futur: „Ich werde *einkaufen*.“

**Sein**

- Verlaufsform (†): „Ich bin *gehend*.“
- Perfekt: „Ich bin *gegangen*.“
- Zustandspassiv: „Die Haare sind *gekämmt*.“
- Absentiv: „Ich bin *einkaufen*.“

**Bleiben**

Mit der Kopula „bleiben“ lassen sich zumindest einige Konstruktionen ebenfalls bilden, ohne ungrammatisch zu sein:

- Ich bleibe *gehend*.
- Die Haare bleiben *gekämmt*.
- Ich bleibe *stehen*. (nur bestimmte Verben)

Nun zur Frage: hat „bleiben“ jemals eine Funktion als Hilfsverb gehabt, die über die Funktion als Kopula hinausging?

Comment: Ich habe mir immer gedacht, dass der zweite Teil *stehen* vom Wort *stehenbleiben* etwa wie eine trennbare Vorsilbe wirkt. So habe ich es mindestens verwendet. Kann sein, dass bleiben hier eine Ausnahme ist. Die Antwort weiß ich leider nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Als Hilfsverben kenne ich nur *sein*, *haben* und *werden*. Das schließt zwar weitere nicht aus, aber Deine Argumente für *bleiben* kann ich entkräften:

- Ich fahre vorausschauend.
- Ich fahre angeschnallt.
- Ich fahre einkaufen.

Wurde *fahren* jemals als Hilfsverb verwendet?